# spring no mapea mi tabla de la base de datos postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring

hola que tal buenas tardes, tengo una duda, tengo una tabla en la base de datos con nombre System_user y lo llamo dentro de mi modelo, de la  clase Dashboard

el detalle es que la tabla empieza con la letra mayuscula y ya probe en ponerlo entre comillas y aun asi no me lo reconoce

```
@Entity("\"System_user\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Entity solo le dice a tu proveedor de persistencia que esa clase sera una entidad.

El proveedor de persistencia usualmente usa el nombre de la clase para mapearlo contra el nombre de la tabla.

Para ser mas explicito en como mapear esa clase contra la base de datos, debes adicionar tambien @Table.

Ahora, te recomendaria cambiar el nombre de la tabla o validar que no este repetida en los esquemas por defecto que trae la base de datos, porque luego puede ser un problema, usualmente todas tienes tablas User.